# Getting an error when trying to use a function, not sure why

Tags: c++, vector

I have defined the function above the `main` function and then when I try to use my defined function, I keep getting the error:

`Parse Issue Expected '(' for function- style cast or type construction.`

```
colorPath(const vector<vector<int> >& geoData2D, vector <vector<int> >& redVec;, vector <vector<int> >& greenVec,vector <vector<int> >& blueVec, 252, 25, 63, q);
```

Comment: You have an extra `;` in there.

Comment: yes i just realized that. I removed it and still get the error

Comment: If you're trying to call the function, you don't need to put the variable types. Just `colorPath(geoData2D, redVec, ...)`

Comment: Okay i will try that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between declaring a function *signature*, and *calling* the function. The *signature* just tells the compiler what arguments the funtion takes:

```
void colorPath(const vector<vector<int> >&, vector<vector<int> >&, vector<vector<int> >&, vector<vector<int> >&, int, int, int, int);
```

Not sure what variable type `q` is, but let's assume it's an `int`.

Then there's actually *calling* the function, in which you don't need to include the argument types:

```
colorPath(geoData2D, redVec, greenVec, blueVec, 252, 25, 63, q);
```

Of course, you also need to *define* the function elsewhere in your program, presumably underneath your `main` function, or even in another file entirely:

```
void colorPath(const vector<vector<int> >& geoData2D, vector<vector<int> >& redVec, vector<vector<int> >& greenVec, vector<vector<int> >& blueVec, int red, int green, int blue, int alpha) {
    // function implementation
}
```